# Sentinel use Sentry::check() return nothing

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel and sentinal. I have created a controller and checking for the user login in the index method. Below is my code.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\admin;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Cartalyst\Sentinel\Laravel\Facades\Sentinel;

class PackageController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        var_dump(Sentry::check());
    }
}
```

when I call package in the url, then the shows nothing in the browser. 
I have also tried to change the line "use Cartalyst\Sentinel\Native\Facades\Sentinel;" to "use Cartalyst\Sentinel\Laravel\Facades\Sentinel;" noting change. Please Suggest where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the namespace is correct.

```
use Cartalyst\Sentinel\Laravel\Facades\Sentinel;
```

but the class name should be,

```
Sentinel::check();
```

Comment: I have change with this var_dump(Sentinel::check()); but still same not showing anything.

Comment: @Susain are you getting any errors? or NULL value? or blank page?

Comment: It's showing Blank page, and also if I used the same in thing in the middleware it shows me error as "Class sentinel does not exist"

Comment: @Susain did u mention the namespace in middleware?

Comment: my middleware has only one namespace "App\Http\Middleware;". Is there anyone other namespace also, that I am missing??

Comment: yes. you need to add the sentinel namespace in your middleware, which is mentioned in my answer